# JSP cookies[loop].getValue() breaking when @ is a vaule

Tags: jsp, cookies

I have set a cookie to an email address for a low level login. When i get the value of the cookie it does not return anything past the @ sign?

For example :

cookie value = 'name@domain.com'

cookie get value = 'variable = cookies[loop].getValue()'

Returns = 'name'

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Possibly escape the characters?

Answer (score 0):

The `@` is an invalid character in a cookie. I suggest to URL-encode and URL-decode the cookie value.

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name, URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
// ...
```

and

```
String value = URLDecoder.decode(cookie.getValue(), "UTF-8");
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your time,

I'm getting an error 'can not reslove symbol pointing at the URL... ' when using you code though:

Cookie cookieUserId = new Cookie("cookieUserId", URLEncoder.encode(emailAddress, "UTF-8"));

Does this mean I need to install URLEcoder?

I'm running this on Apache Tomcat/4.1.40 and it has only recently become a problem.

Comment: It's from the `java.net` package: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html Just add `import java.net.URLEncoder;` to top of your class (or let your IDE autocomplete it?).

Answer (score -1):

### Declaration of cookie

```
enter code here
   String str="name@domain.com";
    str=URLEncoder.encode(str);
    Cookie ck2=new Cookie("email",str);
```

===============================================================

```
    String a = URLDecoder.decode(cks[i].getValue());
```

---

this will get you cookie all characters including @, after@